# Guess the hat colors - Riddle 6

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, liars, meta-knowledge, hat-guessing

And for today, a new original hat guessing puzzle!

**CHALLENGE:** Guess the hats of the 4 prisoners.

**SPECIAL RULE:** One of the prisoners is lying

[image: picture of the 4 prisoners]

**DESCRIPTION:** Each one can see the hats that are in front of them, and not their own.

They give some tips about what they see (remember one of them is lying):

1- **A** sees **B**, **C** and **D**, but he says he only sees 1 green hat.

2- **B** sees **C** and **D**, and he assures he sees a green hat on both of them.

3- **D**, who is looking in the opposite direction, can see **A**, **B** and **C**, and claims to see 2 green hats together.

There are 2 green hats and 2 black hats, so everybody must wear a hat.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A and B have green hats, C and D have black hats.

Reasoning:

> If A is lying, then B and D must be telling the truth. If B is telling the truth, then C and D must be the two green hats, but then D would be lying because he can't see his own hat.
>  Therefore, A must be telling the truth, and since he and B are looking the same direction, B must be lying. That means D must be a truth teller.
>  So A can only see one green, therefore his own hat must be green (since he can see everybody but his own). Since D is telling the truth and the two greens are next to each other, B must have the second green. That leaves C and D as black.

Comment: well done! nice reasoning

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler way to identify the liar.  The end is like Anthony's answer.

> - A and B contradict each other.  If B sees 2 green hats, A should too.
>   - B and D contradict each other.  If B sees 2 green hats, D should see only one.
>   - So B is the liar.  The others tell the truth.
>   - A sees 1 green hat, so he must wear the other one.
>   - D sees 2 green hats together, that must be A's and B's.  C and D wear black hats.